# Why does creating a file inside a docker-machine VM result in permission denied?

Tags: bash, docker, sh, boot2docker, docker-machine

I want to create the file /etc/docker/daemon.json in a vm created using docker-machine by SSHing into it as follows

```
docker-machine ssh manager1 "sudo echo \"{ \"insecure-registries\":[\"192.168.100.99:5000\"] }\" >| /etc/docker/daemon.json"
```

The above fails with the message

`sh: can't create /etc/docker/daemon.json: Permission denied`

How can the above be achieved similar to how I've tried to do it since I need this to be placed in a non-interactive bash script.

Comment: You can take a look at the UID and GID in the container and see, that they are kind of interesting... I managed creating files by adding a shell script, which sets the correct permissions, e.g. for the www-data user. However, I am not satisfied with this "solution".

Comment: You can create a boot2docker custom iso with your own modifications... maybe this is like crack a nut with sledgehammer... but it works.

Comment: Thanks for both your suggestions. BMitch's answer below worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command runs the echo as root but the output is handled by the shell redirection which is running as your user. Try instead the following usage of piping to sudo running tee:

```
docker-machine ssh manager1 "echo \"{ \\\"insecure-registries\\\":[\\\"192.168.100.99:5000\\\"] }\" \
  | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json"
```

Note I also escaped the quotes inside your echo one more time, otherwise the quotes get eaten by the shell/echo command.

---

For this specific use case, I'd recommend creating your machines with:

```
docker machine create --engine-insecure-registry 192.168.100.99:5000 ...
```

in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Both your solutions work. I went with the latter as it seems to be the better way for this particular use case as you suggested.